# Album Release Dates - Echonest

Tags: api, echonest

I'm trying to find release dates for albums -- On an old EchoNest forum they noted they launched a soft release of the feature using the following call:

http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/song/search?api_key=BLAHBLAHBLAH&format=xml&results=4&artist=adele&bucket=id:spotify-WW&bucket=tracks&limit=true

When I insert my API Key into the call it doesn't return album or album release date info.  I was just wondering if they are no longer offering this feature or there is another way to find release dates on EchoNest.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Echonest does not provides release dates directly. Instead you can use spotify api using spotify:album:id elements from the echonest query:

https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/1eKiA8MvAVkrB78dYvYRU0

or you can use MusicBrainz API

[musicbrainz api get all release groups and release dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526584/musicbrainz-api-get-all-release-groups-and-release-dates)